# Inappropriate value for attribute "triggers": map of string required

Tags: terraform

Running into error "Inappropriate value for attribute "triggers": map of string required."

Trying to use local-exec provisioner which should trigger before the creation of a particular resource in this case "monitor"

```
resource "null_resource" "test_run" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "bin/script.sh"
    interpreter = ["bash", "-File"]
  }

  triggers {
    before = "${bigip_ltm_monitor.millenium}"
  }
}

resource "bigip_ltm_monitor" "millenium" {
  compatibility = "enabled"
  interval      = "5"
  name          = "/Common/https_mon"
  parent        = "/Common/https"
  receive       = "200"
  reverse       = "disabled"
  send          = "GET /health HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: xyz.com\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n"
  timeout       = "16"
}
```

Comment: Please share the full *millenium* attribute of *monitor*

Comment: @rflume Please take a look.

Comment: Error message is valid: you have a `Map[Map[String]]` instead of `Map[String]` for `triggers`. Couple of things here: what version of Terraform and could you `terraform fmt` your config to make it readable please?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I am using terraform 0.12

Comment: At first I thought that was JSON formatted from the nesting but it seems to be a bizarre HCL format that is apparently valid. I've edited to a more canonical style to make it readable to other users of Terraform but roll it back if there's a very good reason it should be in that format.

Comment: Now that I've changed the format to a more canonical style HCL that looks like it should be fine so now I'm worried that that edit has made the question invalid. It would probably help if you could expand on why you were trying to use HCL in that format in the first place.

Comment: So I am working on a PoC. Since terraform supports json input, I am actually working with configuration file in json format i.e configuratuion.tf.json as I can automate this in later stage. For the convenience of stack overflow users, I am converting my .json file into .tf file using https://github.com/kvz/json2hcl. This is the reason for this HCL format.

Comment: The format of the original question did not appear to be valid JSON, so @ydaetskcoR may have the correct theory here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  purpose of the `triggers` argument is to specify a collection of strings that the `null_resource` implementation can check for changes to decide whether to replace the object, which would in turn re-run the provisioner.

If you need `null_resource.test_run` to be created *before* `bigip_ltm_monitor.millenium` is created then you need to write the dependency edge the other way, inside the `bigip_ltm_monitor`. For example:

```
resource "bigip_ltm_monitor" "millenium" {
  compatibility = "enabled"
  interval      = "5"
  name          = "/Common/https_mon"
  parent        = "/Common/https"
  receive       = "200"
  reverse       = "disabled"
  send          = "GET /health HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: xyz.com\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n"
  timeout       = "16"

  depends_on = [null_resource.test_run]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `depends_on = [null_resource.test_run]` in your *bigip_ltm_monitor* resource **instead** of `triggers{...}` in your *null_resource*.

This lets Terraform create the provisioner resource prior to the monitor.

See [Resource Dependencies](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/dependencies.html)
 for more information.

Comment: This isn't necessary and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @rflume Appreciate your suggestion. I am aware of this workaround but I am working on bigip provider and creating various monitors, nodes, pools etc. Idea here is to make trigger option work so that I can execute a bash script before creating other resources like monitors and nodes that too without complicating my dependency tree much.